# Flutter - How to navigate on notification when app is closed

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How do you navigate in flutter when you open a notification when the app is closed?

This is my code which I call from the main function:

```
final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
_fcm.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage message) { 
  if (message != null && message.data != null) {
      Keys.navKey.currentState.pushNamed(Routes.messageDetail);
  } 
});
```

In my main.dart I set the navigatorKey of my MaterialApp:

```
 MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: Keys.navKey,)
```

And navKey is a static variable:

```
class Keys {
  static final navKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

If I open a notification when the app is closed, I receive this error:

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'pushNamed' was called on null.
> Receiver: null Tried calling: pushNamed("MESSAGEDETAIL")

I can navigate elsewhere in the app with the navigation key.

Is there another way to do this or  how can I make sure the  navigationKey is initialized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` to handle message in background

Example:

```
void handleMessageOnBackground() {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(
      (remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage != null) {
          String payload = json.encode(remoteMessage.data);
          //navigator two orther screen
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

And init `handleMessageOnBackground()` in `home_screen.dart` , not `main.dart`

`main.dart` > `splash_screen` > `home_screen`

Comment: Thanks, I moved the getInitialMessage() to my home screen instead of the main.dart and now it works.

Comment: Yeb, your navigatorKey need to initial before run method navigator to new screen, so we need run navigator after navigatorKey already initialized in main.dart